# Why this give me a segfault?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

Here is my code, I'm getting a segmentation fault and I don't know why... I'm creating a grid which 'n' is its size, 'tab' is an array which his type is cellule : a cell has 2 values. So I'm creating in the function 'creer_grille' an array I malloc it (size can be 4 6 or 8) and I initialize the cells values with -1 and 0. Then in the following function I'm testing the 'creer_grille' function.

```
typedef struct
{
    int val;
    int initial;
} cellule;

typedef struct
{
    cellule  *tab;
    int      n;
} grille;

grille  *creer_grille(int n)
{
    grille *g;
  int    i;

  assert(n == 4 || n == 6 || n == 8 && "Taille de la grille différent de 4,6 ou 8");
    g->n = n;
    g = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n*n));
        if (g->tab == NULL)
                exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
      {
        g->tab[i].val = -1;
        g->tab[i].initial = 0;
      }
      return g;
}

void detruire_grille(grille * g)
{
  free(g);
}

void test_creer_grille(){
    int i,k;
    for(k = 4; k <= 8 ; k+=2){
        grille * g = creer_grille(k);
        assert(g->n == k && "Problème dans le champ n de la grille");

        //Vérification que les cellules sont vides
        for(i = 0 ; i < k * k ; i++){
            assert(g->tab[i].val == -1 && "Problème : cellule non vide !");
            assert(g->tab[i].initial == 0 && "Problème : cellule initiale !");
        }
        detruire_grille(g);
    }
    printf("Test de la fonction creer_grille OK !\n");
}

int    main()
{
   test_creer_grille();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems. Suggested fixed code

```
grille  *creer_grille(int n)
{
    grille *g = malloc(sizeof(grille)); // A <=== Allocate Grille
    int    i;

    assert((n == 4 || n == 6 || n == 8) // B <=== ()
       && "Taille de la grille différent de 4,6 ou 8");
    g->n = n;
    g->tab = malloc(sizeof(cellule) * (n*n)); // C <=== sizeof(cellule)
    if (g->tab == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        g->tab[i].val = -1;
        g->tab[i].initial = 0;
    }
    return g;
}

void detruire_grille(grille * g)
{
    free (g->tab);  // D <=== free first the Cellules
    free(g);
}
```

Explanation

- A) Need to allocate the Grille
- B) Parentheses are necessary since `&&` has more precedence than `||`
- C) use `sizeof(cellule)` and not `sizeof(int)`
- D) The Cellules also have to be freed (and before Grille)

Answer (score 1):

In your `creer_grille` function, you declare the `g` pointer. As it is not initialized, it will contain garbage.

Few lines later, you try to access the `n` member of `g` (`g->n`). Even at this time, your `g` pointer is not initialized. Therefore, you try to access a garbage location which for obvious reasons will lead to a segmentation fault.

A possible fix is to allocate memory for your `g` pointer before using it.

`g = malloc(sizeof(grille));`

I suspect that your compiler might have warned you about using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this function : creer_grille(int n)
the variable g is dynamically allocated with the size of sizeof(int)*n*n

but during the loop you are accessing the cellule field, that was not allocated explicitly.
You are allocation g and testing (g->tab == NULL). This works for you because malloc is not setting the allocated memory to 0. if you used calloc - you could see the problem.

When you will try to set the initial field in the cullule in the n*n'th iteration - you will get the segmentation fault.